# best way to call a Python method under multiple conditions

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

I have a workflow in which I need to call a python method when either of:

1. specified timeout occurs, or

2. size of input data (list) reaches a threshold, like 10 data points

What is the best way to support the workflow?

[Edit] - The methods would be called in a serverless API so it needs to be stateless. Does it make sense to use  some sort of queues to store and retrieve the data and how?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
while True: #Keep checking condition
    if timeoutCondition or len([list]) > 10: #check conditions
        class.method() #execute method
```

Comment: I just added the scenario where I need to use this workflow. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the status at a certain interval, if timeout or data reaches threshold, do the thing you want.

```
import time

max_count = 10
timeout = 60 #1min

count_increase = 0
next_timeout = time.time() + timeout

while True:
    current_time = time.time
    count_increase = get_count() - count
    if count >= max_count or current_time >= next_timeout:
        do_what_you_want()
        count_increase = 0
        next_timeout = time.time() + timeout

    time.sleep(1)
```